# Skills to help the group

Tags: clicker-heroes

I am looking to streamline my progression through ascensions. For the most part I skip upgrading people that do not give me the skills I can activate but I want to take that one step further.

What are the skill names and who are the heroes/gods that have skills that will boost the entire team's DPS instead of just their own?

Comment: Don't forget to level these heroes up at the end of your ascension! You get an extra hero soul for every 2k hero levels.

Comment: @Arperum Indeed Indeed!

Comment: There exist some list of all upgrades on the wiki, can't look it up now though (at work). So whoever feels like it can filter the list.

Comment: @Arperum Done. Also, once your optimal run is in the 10s of K of hero souls per ascension, the 20 odd souls from leveling up heroes to the maximum buyable level seem completely not worth doing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Heroes that have group DPS boosting skills:

- The Wandering Fisherman (lvl 75: 25%)
- Betty Clicker (lvl 10: 20%, 25: 20%, 50: 20%, 75: 20%)
- Leon (lvl 75: 25%)
- Broyle Lindeoven, Fire Mage (lvl 10: 25%)
- Amenhotep (lvl 25: 20%, 50: 20%)
- Beastlord (lvl 75: 10%)
- Shinatobe, Wind Deity (lvl 25: 10%)
- Grant, The General (lvl 10: 25%, 50: 25%)
- Frostleaf (lvl 50: 25%)

Heroes that increase gold found:

- King Midas (lvl 10: 25%, 25: 25%, 50: 25%, 75: 50%)

Special

- Abaddon (lvl 75): unlocks The Dark Ritual, which will increase your DPS with 5% every cast
- Aphrodite (lvl 100): unlocks Energize, which will double the effect of the next skill used, so The Dark Ritual can increase DPS by 10%
- Shinatobe, Wind Deity (lvl 100) : unlocks Reload, which reduces the cooldown of the previously used skill with one hour, which can be used to cast The Dark Ritual more often.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a text file that breaks it down similarly but I find it easier to refer to. Let me explain:

```
Hero name   DPS upg lvl Gold upg lvl    Click upg lvl           Skill upg lvl
-----------|-----------|---------------|-----------------------|---------------
Cid         -           -               150,125,100,75,50,10*   25 Clickstorm
Treebeast   -           -               100                     -
Ivan        -           -               100                     75 Powersurge
Brittany    -           -               -                       -
TW Fishermn 75          -               100                     -
Betty       75,50,25,10 -               -                       -
TM Samurai  -           -               -                       -
Leon        75          -               -                       -
TGF Seer    -           -               -                       -
Alexa       -           -               75,10                   100 Lucky Strks
Natalia     -           -               -                       -
Mercedes    -           -               100                     -
Bobby       -           -               100                     -
Broyle      10          -               -                       100 Metal Detr
Sir George  -           -               100                     -
King Midas  -           75,50,25,10     125                     100 Golden Clk
Referi Jer. -           -               125                     -
Abaddon     -           -               -                       75 Dark Ritual
Ma Zhu      -           -               -                       -
Amenhotep   50,25       -               -                       150 Ascension
Beastlord   75          -               -                       100 Super Clks
Athena      -           -               -                       -
Aphrodite   -           -               -                       100 Energize
Shinatobe   25          -               -                       100 Reload
Grant       50,10       -               -                       -
Frostleaf   50          -               75                      -
Dread Knt   -           -               -                       -
Atlas       -           -               -                       -
Terra       -           -               -                       -
Phthalo     -           -               -                       -
OGD Banana  -           -               -                       -
Lilin       -           -               -                       -
Cadmia      -           -               -                       -
Alabaster   -           -               -                       -
Astraea     -           -               -                       -


So, quick buy-all-upgrades ramp up is:
q TW Fishermn 75
q Betty       75
q Leon        75
q Broyle      10
q King Midas  75
q Abaddon     75*
q Amenhotep   50 (150*)
q Beastlord   75
q Aphrodite   100*
q Shinatobe   100*
q Grant       50
q Frostleaf   50

Dark Ritual weavable pattern
  T Skill   Xdps    =+%dps
  0 8 6 9   x1.10   10
 15 8 9
 30 8 6 9   x1.10   21
 45 8 9
 60 8 6 9   x1.10   33.1
 75 8 9
 90 8 6 9   x1.10   46.41
105 8 9
120 8 6 9   x1.10   61.051
135 8 9
150 8 6 9   x1.10   77.1561
etc

Dark Ritual non weavable pattern
  T Skill   Xdps    =+%dps
  0 8 6 9   x1.10   10
 15 8 9 6   x1.05   15.5
 30 9 8
 45 9 8 6   x1.10   27.05
 60 9 8
 75 9 8 6   x1.10   39.755
 90 9 8     
105 9 8 6   x1.10   53.7305
120 9 8     
135 9 8 6   x1.10   69.10355
150 9 8     
etc
```

So based on this my minimal buy of heroes lower than the highest buyable hero via a carry over from a clickable (goldfish) gift are:

```
75 Fisherman
75 Betty
10 Broyle
75 Midas
50 Amenhotep
75 Beastlord
25 Shinatobe
50 Grant
50 Frostleaf
```

With optionally (for skills)

```
 75 Abaddon
100 Aphrodite
100 Shinatobe
```

But really just control clicking:

> Fisherman, Betty, Leon, Broyle, Midas, Abaddon, Amenhotep, Beastlord,
>   Shinatobe, Grant, and Frostleaf

and then clicking "Buy all upgrades" is easiest.